# Vue component/element creating while method is working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, vue-component

I have a parser method inside my component, when that method is working I want to create components (or even just elements) from values that is computed. Is it possible to creating component or html elements when method is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to creating component or html elements when method is working?

Its not possible in JavaScript **using synchronous code**. JavaScript is single-threaded and even browser rendering is blocked when your synchronous/long running code is executing, not to mention Vue logic which re-renders your template and updates the DOM ([really recommend this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) - explains the problem beautifully)

You have basically two options:

1. Split up you workload into smaller chunks, process only one at a time and use `setTimeout(nextBatch, 0)` to schedule "next chunk" processing. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16353240/381282) for more details...
2. You can offload your computation to [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) which is running in its own thread but brings new challenges (for example data between your Vue app and Web Worker need to be serialized/deserialized on both sides)