# Trigger a re-render within a Vue async watch before a blocking operation

Tags: vuejs2

I have an async watch that fetches some data from the server. It will batch process the Response in a blocking operation. I am trying to update the view before kicking off the blocking operation, like so:

```
Vue.component("foo-bar", {
    ...
    watch: {
        async things() {
            const response = await API.getThings();
            this.someUIMessage = `processing ${response.length} things...`;
            someBlockingOperation(response);
        }
    }
}
```

But `this.someUIMessage` is not updated in the view until *after* `someBlockingOperation`. I stuck an `await Vue.nextTick()` in between setting the string and calling the blocking op, and `this.$forceUpdate()`, but without success.

What *does* work (sometimes! depends on what else is going on in the app) is calling `setTimeout(() => someBlockingOperation(response), 0)`, but that seems like a kludge. Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: yes, fixed (only a typo in the snippet, the actual code has the `await`)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to show some more code because your use case is exactly described in the docs - [Async Update Queue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue) and `await Vue.nextTick()` *should* work

If your `someBlockingOperation` take too long, it may be worth to think about UI responsiveness anyway and maybe apply a strategy of splitting up you workload into smaller chunks, process only one at a time and use `setTimeout(nextBatch, 0)` to schedule "next chunk" processing. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16353240/381282) for more details...