# Constantly random value showing in homepage

Tags: javascript, loops

I am a js beginner.
I want to show some random float value between 1 to 50, just the demo value of sensor data.
That's the code I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  while(1)
  {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.random()*50 + 1 ;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But it didn't work. Can anyone help?
I want to show the number when the page loaded and constantly changing the value like dynamic data.

Comment: You need to use a timer, via either `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`. The browser will not render the view while your loop is running.

Comment: Also, you're not calling your "myFunction".

Comment: You'll need to remove the `while` call, and call the function you have there in a `setInterval` call. Finally, you probably want to round the random value, otherwise you'll get a float between 1 and 51.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 problems:

1. you defined function, but it is not called anywhere
2. while (1) will not work as you expected,

here is fixed version:

```js
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.random()*50 + 1 ;
}
setInterval('myFunction()', 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">demo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why the setInterval? I don't see any reason why to use setInterval

Comment: @caramba it is part of the question `hen the page loaded, constantly changing the value like dynamic data`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I exactly wanted to do! And a learnt a new concept, interval! thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

`while(1) {...}` won't re-render your document ([here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840527/whiletrue-vs-setintervalfunction-0)). If you want to do some kinda of clock/timer you may use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) or [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). However here is one important thing about this, you need to remember about `clearInterval`/`clearTimeout`, otherwise weird, unexpected things may happen (interval thread might be kept till you close your browser tab or browser).

Here is example code how your problem can be solved:

```js
function updateRandomValue() {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.random()*50 + 1
}

const timerId = setInterval(updateRandomValue, 1000)

document.addEventListener("onbeforeunload", () => clearInterval(timerId))
```

```html
<p id="demo">-</p>
```

Comment: There is no need to `round` as the OP wants " some random float value between 1 to 50"

Answer (score 0):

Your program is caught in an infinite loop in `while(1)`. The browser never gives the control back so that the page can be updated. What you can do is have your loop within a timeout. Like this;

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.random()*50 + 1 ;
}
setInterval(myFunction, 1); // the timeout is in milliseconds. This is almost similar to running in a while loop because "myFunction" will be executed in every millisecond.
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

while (1) won't update your page; it'll just break. You're also never calling the function. Here's your updated script.

```
function updateFunc() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.random()*50 + 1 ;
}
window.setInterval(updateFunc, 1000);
```

Some important notes.
I renamed the function so the code is clearer.
1000 means it will run every second. If you want it faster or slower, change the value. It's in milliseconds.